# Filter between 2 dates using a date from another transction

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a custom record that has 3 fields:

- Sequence Number
- Start Date
- End Date

What I am trying to do is create a search via suitescript that takes a date from an invoice (the date is in a custom field) and find the sequence number that falls within the start date and end date.

I tried using the below filters (myDate = the date from the invoice field which in my example is 9/26/2022) but this did not turn up any results even though there is a custom record with a start date of 9/25/2022 and an end date of 10/1/2022:

```
filters:
   [
      ["custrecord_startDate","onorafter",myDate], 
      "AND", 
      ["custrecord_endDate","onorbefore",myDate]
   ]
```

What would be the best way to filter my results to get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written try substituting the dates:

```
filters:
   [
      ["9/25/2022","onorafter","9/26/2022"], 
      "AND", 
      ["10/1/2022","onorbefore","9/26/2022"]
   ]
```

If that's correct then you have the logic backward

If you want to find the custom records whose start and end bracket the transaction date you need:

```
      ["custrecord_startDate","onorbefore",myDate], 
      "AND", 
      ["custrecord_endDate","notbefore",myDate]
   ]
```

Note the `notbefore` for the end date. This covers the case where the custom record starts but is open-ended. If the end date is never empty, then `onorafter` is the operator to use.